# React /Mui - How to get Zoom to work on initial render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Having trouble getting a simple transintion comp, Material UI `<Zoom>`, to work on load. I try to use a simple conditional to get the content to zoom on reder:

```
<Zoom in={financialData.data !== null }>
```

Here is what I'm checking if not `null`

```
    const [financialData, dispatchFinancialData] = useReducer(reducer, initialStateFinancialData)
```

However wrapping my content in this zoom is currently not getting it working.

Is there another simple way to get the Zoom comp working?

Comment: Please put your code on Codesandbox, so others can reproduce the error and help you.